# SCSS SASS path problem with background-image

Tags: html, css, sass

```
GET file:///C:/public/imgs/avada-movers-homeherobackground-final.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Hi guys, I am struggling with this problem that I can't solve. I have my scss files (in the specific `main.scss` in which I have different heroes imgs as background.
example:

```
background-image: url('/public/imgs/avada-movers-movewithease-background-new.jpg');
```

I already tried

```
background-image: url(../..public/imgs/avada-movers-movewithease-background-new.jpg);
```

But nothing has changed.

This is the folder structure

[FOLDER STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rEL8.png)

Strange thing is that it works perfectly when I run it with Live Server (for Visual Studio Code)

Comment: You can remove the `public dir` from the path as you have already added the images in the public folder just make sure your path should look like this `../imgs/avada-movers-movewithease-background-new.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

> Strange thing is that it works perfectly when i run it with Live Server (for Visual Studio Code)

That isn't strange.

`/` means "Start at the root of the site".

If you open the HTML document at `http://localhost/something/` then the root will e `http://localhost/`

If you open the HTML document at `C:\users\myuser\documents\mywebsite\something` then the root is going to be `C:\`.

---

Design your website to run on a web server.

Test it on a web server when you develop it. You've already observed that live server works fine.

Deploy it to a web server when you put it in to production.

Except in some really unusual edge cases, you shouldn't need to worry about what happens when people just open the HTML document from their local hard drive.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! You're absolute right but the site in question is an excercise for didactic purpose so I think that I need it to be correctly openable from the local hard drive :(

Comment: Then you'd need to take the latter approach (not starting with `/`) and work out the path from the *compiled CSS file* to the image.